# How to convert a dnn site to mobile version?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have a site made by dnn6.i need to add the mobile version of the site.how can i solve this problem.or is it possible to convert mobile compatible site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this. You need to evaluate each and determine the best route the most closely matches your goals and amount of administration that you are comfortable with.  Another thing to keep in mind is the user experience you end up delivering to your visitors.

Probably the most flexible solution is to use [responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_Web_Design) to adjust and change the content and layout according to the dimensions of the device that is currently viewing the site - regardless of the kind of device we're speaking about.  [American Athlete Magazine](http://www.americanathletemag.com/) is a great showcase for this approach.

You can also have a mobile section on your main site, or another site altogether that displays content optimized for mobile viewing. In this scenario, you would create a mobile friendly design that offers the best user experience for mobile visitors, as well as maintain content in a way that is equally friendly.  Then, redirect visitors to the mobile site or mobile section of your site using the built-in redirect tools.  They are in all editions of DNN as of v06.01.05.  An example of this method can be seen with [Day of DotNetNuke](http://dayofdotnetnuke.com/) and its [mobile variant](http://m.dayofdotnetnuke.com/).

There are of course other ways to proceed, but these are the most common.  In either scenario you can use content sharing to make maintaining content easier, but you really should balance ease of administration with the expected user experience of your visitors.

There is a lot more information about the [mobile capabilities in the DotNetNuke Wiki](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/DotNetNuke-61-Developer-Quick-Start.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

There are different approaches like Will stated above.

1. You can create a child portal (yourdomain.com/mobi or mobi.yourdomain.com) and modify an already existing skin (check out codeplex for MIT license mobile skins: http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/site/search?query=mobile%20skin) You'll need to put in a redirect in so when a small display pulls up the site it takes the user to the mobile version. The problem with a child portal is that you will have to maintain two separate versions... so if you plan to make many changes, consider option 2.
2. You could also upload the mobile version of the skin to the root portal, but you'll need to make a skin adjustments as you'll want the mobile skin to pull up a dynamic menu.  If you choose this path, you can use the same instances of modules on separate pages (so you only have to make changes once and it will replicate on the desktop skin and the mobile skin).
3. You can wait a little while... DNN 6.2 is going to be released with mobile redirect capabilities (currently only found in DNN Pro and Enterprise).  I'm not sure if DNN is releasing a mobile skin with the new version.

If you need help, I'm happy to bill you for the right solution :) ack !!